# Непонятное поведение pNotify в вычислении

Tags: javascript

После потери фокуса, если поле заполнено но невалидно почему то выводятся сразу два одинаковых сообщения: Ссылка не введена...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**НУЖНО ЧТО БЫ ВЫВОДИЛОСЬ ТОЛЬКО ОДНО**
Никак не пойму, где ошибка в коде.

```js
// Управляем состоянием кнопки Отправить
// УСЛОВИЯ включения кнопки: 
// значение поля список должно быть отличное от 0
// поле ссылка должно быть не пустое и валидное
var input =  $('#input');
input.bind('focus', function() {

    var select_intent = $('#dropdown_intent_widget').val();

    if (select_intent === '0') {

        // Блокируем кнопку Отправить
        $('#button').attr('class', 'md-btn disabled');
    }
});
input.bind('change focusout', function() {

    var input_val = $(this).val();
    var select_intent = $('#dropdown_intent_widget').val();
    var regexp = new RegExp("^(https|http)(:\/\/)(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z]{2,10})$");

    if (select_intent !== '0') {

        if (regexp.test(input_val)) {

            // Разблокируем кнопку Отправить
            $('#button').attr('class', 'md-btn enable');
        } else {

            // Блокируем кнопку Отправить
            $('#button').attr('class', 'md-btn disabled');

            // Выводим сообщение
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Ошибка',
                text: 'Ссылка не введена или введена в неверном форате',
                type: 'error',
                icon: 'false',
                buttons: {
                    sticker: false
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- поле - список (подгружается динамически в select) -->
<input type="text" id="dropdown_intent_widget" value="0" />

<!-- поле - ссылка -->
<input type="text" id="input" name="input" value="" />

<!-- кнопка - по умолчанию выключена -->
<a id="button" class="md-btn disabled">Отправить</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в pNotify, а в этой строке:

```
input.bind('change focusout', function() {
```

Получается вы вешаете на два события обработку, и когда убираете фокус отрабатывает и `focusout` и `change` если значение поля изменилось, и появляется 2 сообщения, когда значение не меняется отрабатывает только `focusout` и вы думаете что всё работает правильно.

Думаю можно убрать `focusout` и оставить только `change`, получится если убрали фокус и значение в поле осталось прежним событие не отработает, а так при `focusout` получается что вы проверяете правильность значения каждый раз, даже если оно не менялось.

Comment: Да, вы правы Ярослав. Спасибо...